# Visual studio code closing on "Save As"/CTRL+SHIFT+S

Tags: visual-studio-code, gnome, manjaro

I recently started using visual studio code for learning HTML/CSS/JavaScript. This editor seems really nice but I encounter a very annoying issue, which is:

**Visual studio code closes whenever I do a SAVE-AS**

Any lead on what is going on and how to fix it?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Do you anything else bound to `Ctrl+Shift+S`?

Comment: Nope I checked and nothing else is bound to `Ctrl+Shift+S`. It seems that whenever I am trying to use commands from the top bar GUI, Visual studio closes down ...